# How to create an automatic list of words in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I am writing a book in Sphinx (not at all python related). And I have some terms that appear in the text that I would like to list at the end of the pdf. What I want is exactly what can be achieved by the [index](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing) offered by Latex.

I am aware of the `glossary` directive in sphinx, but it clearly does not perform what I want. For example, several terms would not even have a definition, but I want a link to them at the end of the document. Something like this:

```
At page 1:

  Mammal is a type of animal, we all love them...

At page 17:

  Berries are fruits, we all love them...

At the end of the book:

  Index
    berry, 17
    mammal, 1
```

I have read about the `index` role in sphinx documentation, [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/misc.html#index-generating-markup).
It seems perfect for my problem, but it is not clear how to create the index of all the terms in the end.

Is there a command to list all the terms created using

```
.. index: mammal
```

throughout the text? Or is there another directive that gets the job done?

Comment: I don't know of any command that can be run, other than `make <builder>`. Here's an [example output of the Sphinx docs using `make html`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/genindex.html). Sphinx generates the index automatically for any builder. Entries in the index are generated according to the domain and whatever manual entries are in the reStructuredText markup `.. index:: <entries>` for blocks and `:index:` for inline.

Comment: The index works like in LaTeX. Sphinx generates a separate HTML page with all the index contents. you can have simple, double and triple index entries. Sphinx will group them for you. Here is an [example output](http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/genindex.html). Some domains will create their own indices.

Answer (score 1):

The comments were enough for me to figure it out.

The index is automatically generated in html, but it has to be found in the file `genindex.html`, which was hidden in my machine for other reasons.

For the `pdf` output, the index has to be compiled separatedly.

So, no extra command in sphinx, everything is automatic.

Comment: Normally, the index is linked via a HTML page link, but there is a trick to link the index in the navigation bar. You need to create a `genindex.rst`, which can be listed in the `toctree` directive. When the navigation is written and everything is parsed, Sphinx will overwrite genindex.html with the output from the index database.